# Retrofit Query is not working properly?

Tags: android, json, rest, gson, retrofit

i want to fetch the json details from the sever.when i query, it's not working.when i hard code the url it is working..

**CASE 1**

```
 @GET("/quiz/create_json/sub_cat.php?main_cat_id=")
void showSubCategory1(@Query("id") int id,Callback<Object> callback);

  retrofitService.showSubCategory1(id, new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Failure");

        }

        @Override
        public void success(Object list, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Success ");
            Log.d(TAG, "arraystting" + list.toString());

        }
    });
```

**Its giving empty array..**

**CASE 2**

```
@GET("/quiz/create_json/sub_cat.php?main_cat_id=1")
void showSubCategory2(Callback<Object> callback);

retrofitService.showSubCategory2(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Object o, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Success "+o.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failure");

        }
    });
```

Here its giving proper json. issue should be fixed in sever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should specify it like this.

```
@GET("/quiz/create_json/sub_cat.php")
void showSubCategory1(@Query("main_cat_id") int id, Callback<Object> callback);
```

Comment: In Retrofit2, it would be  `@GET("quiz/create_json/sub_cat.php")`